# How to call function from external js file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to increment a button on click from an external js file. When i click on the button i am having an error message telling me that my function increment is not defined. How to reach a function for an external js file in html? Thanks in advance.
[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-sea-pxkni?file=/src/index.js)
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>webpack starterkit</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>People entered:</h1>
    <h2 id="count-el">0</h2>
  </div>
  <button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">Increment</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
let count = 0;
let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el");
console.log(countEl);
 document.getElementById("count-el").innerText = count;

function increment() {
  count = count + 1;
  countEl.innerText = count;

}
increment();
```

Comment: What you're doing should work.

Comment: Make sure it's loading `index.js` correctly.

Comment: Is the script actually located in a "scripts" subdirectory?  Do you see the `console.log`?

Comment: I just tested your code and it worked fine.

Comment: yep, if scrips/index.js loads properly then you should be good.
How do you serve your web content in your development environment ?

Comment: i know it should work just fine but somehow it does not. Please see link to sandbox.https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-sea-pxkni?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @TimRoberts yes the log appears fine on the console but when i click on button increment returns as undefined

Comment: I think @Barmar might be right - the code should work fine (when not in the sandbox?) ...the sandbox may have problems with contexts and your code will work when you replace the line `function increment() {` with `window.increment = function() {`

Comment: The code in your sandbox has `import "./styles.css"`.   That's a node.js feature that only works in a browser when its in a module, and I don't believe it works AT ALL for CSS files.  If you had run this is a real browser with the Javascript console turned on (as I did), you would have seen this immediately.  When I delete that line, it works fine.

Comment: 2nd part of the comment above ;) - sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-lumiere-mx5io?file=/src/index.js

Comment: thanks @webdev-dan it worked with the window.increment